# What is going on with my vertical drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm working on my vertical menu but I hit a wall. For one, the menu looks exactly how I want it to work but unfortunately it's not doing any kind of drop down menuish type things I want. When I get to the product link, it just dissipates from there on. I've tried to do a hover effect but the links down below the product tab just don't show up.

Here's the HTML I'm working right now.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kenneth's new exercise</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kenny.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-ul">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here's the CSS code.

```
     html {
        background:url(wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size:cover;
    }
    body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    li {
        list-style:none;
    }
    .main-nav {
        width:250px;
        background:rgba(180,205,203,1.00);
    }
    .main-nav a {
        display:block;
        padding:10px 0px 10px 20px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        letter-spacing:.2em;
        border-bottom:1px dotted gray;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .main-nav a:hover {
        background:rgba(121,165,162,1.0);

    }
    .main-nav-ul ul {
        display:none;
    }
    .main-nav-ul ul:hover li {
        display:block;
        visibility:visible;
}
```

What do I have to do for the product tab to show all the rest of the links?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.main-nav-ul ul` has `display:none`, so you _can not_ hover over that UL element, yet in the next rule (`.main-nav-ul ul:hover li`) you are trying to format an LI inside that list when the list gets hovered - doesn't make sense. The first level LI is what you can hover over - so you need to make the invisible UL inside it visible, when the LI gets hovered.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call the hover on the li and wrap the ul inside it

```
.main-nav-ul li:hover ul {
        display:block;
        visibility:visible;
```

css:

```
<li>
<a href="">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Modar Na said, you just have your `li` and `ul` mixed up. The CSS is a little asymmetrical, though, so I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0qtjpa6/1/) with the `li` and `ul` switched but also a bit of code that makes it, in my opinion, look a bit better. So you have your dropdown, and also a bit of styling. The code is here, but you can just click on the jsfiddle link.
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kenneth's new exercise</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kenny.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-ul">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="drop"><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
        background:url(wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size:cover;
    }
    body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    li {
        list-style:none;
    }
    .main-nav {
        width:250px;
        padding: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
        background:rgba(180,205,203,1.00);
    }
    .main-nav a {
        display:block;
        padding:10px 0px 10px 20px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        letter-spacing:.2em;
        border-bottom:1px dotted gray;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .main-nav a:hover {
        background:rgba(121,165,162,1.0);

    }
    .main-nav-ul ul {
        display:none;
    }
    .main-nav li:hover ul {
        display:block;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    .drop {
        position:relative;
        left:-20px;  
    }
    }
```